# how to configure hadoop so that namenode gets started without reformatting on reboot

Tags: hadoop, format

Namenode is missing every time the hadoop is started after a reboot. hadoop namenode -format corrects this problem at the cost of losing files through format. How to prevent formatting and preserve namenode files

Answer (score 0):

put the following configuration in you `hdfs-site.xml`

```
  $vi hdfs-site.xml
```

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
  <description>Default block replication. The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
   </description>
 </property>


<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hduser/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/hduser/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

the `dfs.name.dir` Determines where on the local file system the DFS name node should store the name table(fsimage).The name table is replicated in all of the directories, for redundancy

the `dfs.data.dir` Determines where on the local file system an DFS data node should store its blocks.Data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices. Directories that do not exist are ignored.

Comment: What changes is to be incorporated when using a single node setup having <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>.

Comment: if you are using a single node cluster set the dfs replication to 1 if you are using a multi node cluster ,set it to 2,

Comment: It is set to 1. My primary question is regarding how to load the file system on hadoop fs upon reboot (and avoid hadoop namenode -format everytime i reboot my node to start namenode). On my search on internet I've found there is something called Namenode's safemode (Page 21,http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/hadoop/02-HDFS_2-InstallationAndShell.pdf ) which loads file system state from fsimage and edits-log files. How can I use this to preserve the state of my file system?

Comment: I think that the safemode is by default on.In order to forcefully let the namenode leave safemode, following command should be executed:

"bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave"